# What is the convention of separating APIs as modules in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express

Here is how my app.js looks like...

I want to know how do I separate this single file into multiple files for better code quality. How do we do that?

**My idea is to have the below files...**
server.js -> for server related properties 
serve.js -> this becomes the main file in the package.json 
apis -> this shall be the file with apis, I shd be able to separate apis depending upon the modules too...

What is the preferred convention in NodeJS? I am sure that we do not want to write all apis in one single file.

```js
    const express = require('express') // import express module
    const app = express() // initiate express app
    app.use(express.json()) // not sure what this is but without it POST cant read the JSON parameters from the body
    const host = 'localhost' // host
    const port = process.env.PORT || 1338 // pick port
    const routePrefix = '/' + 'api' + '/' // this is the route prefix used from where the APIs will be accesssed

    const routes = { // define routes
    root: routePrefix + 'root',
    test: routePrefix + 'test',
    items: routePrefix + 'items',
    item: routePrefix + 'items/:id'
}

    // print details
    function printDetails(currentRoute, requestMethod, requestParams, 
    requestQuetyString) {
       console.log(currentRoute, requestMethod, requestParams, requestQuetyString);
    }

    // get root
    app.get(routes.root, (req, res) => {
        printDetails(routes.root, req.method, req.params, req.query)
        res.send(routes.root)
    })

    // get test route
    app.get(routes.test, (req, res) => {
        printDetails(routes.test, req.method, req.params, req.query)
        res.send(routes.test)
    })

    // for the web server
    app.use(express.static('../public')) // this is where static files reside and need to be served to for the clientside app

    // start the API server and Web server
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`
        \nExpress Server started on port ${port}..
        APIs can be accessed at http://${host}:${port}${routePrefix}
        Web Server started on port http://${host}:${port}
        `)
    })
```

I have tried it on my own and the respective files look like this. However, I am unable to run this.

server.js

```js
const express = require('express') // import express module
const app = express() // initiate express app
app.use(express.json()) // not sure what this is but without it POST cant read the JSON parameters from the body
//const api = require('./apis')
//const app = api.app
const host = 'localhost' // host
const port = process.env.PORT || 1338 // pick port
const routePrefix = '/' + 'api' + '/' // this is the route prefix used from where the APIs will be accesssed
const routes = { // define routes
    root: routePrefix + 'root',
    test: routePrefix + 'test',
    items: routePrefix + 'items',
    item: routePrefix + 'items/:id'
}
// for the web server
app.use(express.static('../public')) // this is where static files reside and need to be served to for the clientside app

module.exports = {
    app: app,
    host: host,
    port: port,
    routePrefix: routePrefix,
    routes: routes
}
```

serve.js

```js
const server = require('./server') // import server module
//const app = server.app

// start the API server and Web server
server.app.listen(server.port, () => {
    console.log(`
    \nExpress Server started on port ${server.port}..
    APIs can be accessed at http://${server.host}:${server.port}${server.routePrefix}
    Web Server started on port http://${server.host}:${server.port}
    `)
})
```

api.js

```js
'use strict'
const server = require('./server') // import sever module
const app = server.app

// get test route
app.get(server.routes.test, (req, res) => {
    printDetails(server.routes.test, req.method, req.params, req.query)
    res.send(server.routes.test)
})

module.exports = {

}
```

The problem I am facing is how do I use module.exports and what do I need to export from what module. My requirement is when I run "node serve.js", I should be able to run the APIs and they should be available for the client. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following structure is much more maintainable and easier to understand (also this is the more commonly used structure in new web apps in node):

```
├───client        <-- Your web client application directory
│   └───assets
├───common        <-- Common (shared) files between client and server
└───server        <-- Your SugoiJS server directory
    ├───config    <-- Build config (environment, webpack)
    │   └───webpack
    └───src       <-- Your server app source code
        ├───app   <-- Bootstrap module, Server initialize and listener files, 'authorization' class(optional)
        │   └───classes
        ├───config     <-- Server configuration (services, paths, etc.)
        └───modules    <-- All of you application modules
            └───index  <-- Single module
                ├───controllers    <-- Modules' controllers
                ├───models         <-- Modules' models(optional)
                └───services       <-- Modules' services
```

This is taken from SugoiJS framework.
https://wiki.sugoijs.com/get-started

Then basically all the routes you are writing will be controllers :)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the right structure. However, for now my problem is not able to export the express app (app variable in server.js). i should be able access that in all the other API files like api.js and make them work. How do I do that?

Comment: Hi, I think that what you are looking for is the exports function and then just map the routes to the correct controller / function. Here are some examples for express:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes#Create_the_route-handler_callback_functions
and then mapping it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes#Create_the_catalog_route_module

Or in case you are going to use SugoiJS, you simply define @controller: https://wiki.sugoijs.com/sugoi-server/define-route-controller

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to split up JS code into files, the simplest way (that is still quite efficient) is to **require modules**. Here's a [full guide](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8), and here's a minimal demo:

```
// lib.js
module.exports = {
  x: 10,
  y: () => 20
}

// index.js
const lib = require('./lib');
console.log(lib.x); // 10
console.log(lib.y()); // 20
```

To keep the code clear, simple and efficient, requiring a module should not have any side effects (ie deleting a file, or making requests): for example, define a Class inside a module, and export it.

There are other ways to split up code between files, such as [import/export](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/a-simple-intro-to-javascript-imports-and-exports-389dd53c3fac).

Comment: I have figured out that I need to use module exports. However I couldnt figure out what shd be exported and how to use it on the other module. My problem is I want to import server.app in all the other modules and it should work. I am unable to make it work.

Comment: If you're writing an API, export the request handler functions in files like `handlers/<api-path>`, then import them in `server.js`, where you'll use your handlers. (that's just one workflow amongst many).